# Root user can't connect to any database with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm using MongoDB with Docker and want to automate the database creation. 
I found that when passing `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD` environment variables to the docker run command I can create a new root user on the admin database.

My issue starts when I'm trying to create a new database and create collections in it.

I wrote a script that selects the admin database, authenticate into the mongo service and creates new db, but for some reasons I can not access the database with my credentials..

```
use admin;
db.auth('myuser', 'mypassword');
use newDatabase;
db.createCollection('newCol');
```

when trying to authenticate to `newDatabase` with the given credentials (myuser and mypassword) I found that I do not have the needed permissions to the db.

What did I do wrong? How can I do it automatically anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I just understood that the root cannot access the other databases for some reasons, so I used `db.createUser` and created a new user just for the new database.